# Ionic don't run android into Genymotion

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, adb, genymotion

I have get everything setup by following on this tutorial (http://learn.ionicframework.com/videos/windows-android/). The problem is now, when I run `ionic run android`, the adb doesn't get the apk install into the virtual device run by Genymotion.

However, if I manually navigate to `platforms\android\build\outputs\apk\` folder and run `adb install android-debug.apk`, then run `ionic run android` again, it will install into the virtual device. Everytime after I did the changes, I need to run `adb install`, then it will work.

How can I overcome it? Thanks.

Comment: You should always be *inside* the project folder in order to run `ionic run android`. Are you doing that? Question is not quite clear.

Comment: @DineshDevkota Yeah, I am inside project folder when running `ionic run android`. Anyway, I found out the issue is actually due to old version of Android as I was testing on Android 4.1.1. When switching to Android 5.0, the problem solved.